# Media Recorder to record video with Camera 2 API throws -2147483648 prepared

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I am trying to record a video with the Camera2 API with the MediaRecorder class which I am calling from a Service. But I face the error `prepare failed: -2147483648` while calling the `MediaRecorder.prepare()` method.

I found this only happening in Android 10 and above devices, where Android 9.1 and 5.1.1 able to record it without any errors.

I have put the necessary permissions and service elements in the Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

----------------

<service android:name="xyz.kumaraswamy.procam.CameraService"
                 android:exported="true"/>
```

And all of the above permissions are allowed in the App.

My app targets Android 10. As per the Android docs, it is necessary to add the attribute `foregroundServiceType` to the service element, (`android:foregroundServiceType="camera|microphone" />` in my case). And start it with foregroundServiceType as one of the parameters to `startForeground`.

This is the reason I think the media recorder is failing to prepare while the preview initializes fine .

Below is the method that is responsible to start the video recording.

```
public void recordVideo(@NonNull final String recordingPath) {
        cameraCaptureSessions.close();
        cameraCaptureSessions = null;

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1000000);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(videoDimension.getWidth(), videoDimension.getHeight());
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(new File(recordingPath).getAbsolutePath());
        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(this.previewSurface);

        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare(); // error
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        final SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(videoDimension.getWidth(), videoDimension.getHeight());

        final Surface recordSurface = mediaRecorder.getSurface();
        try {
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(recordSurface);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

            ImageReader mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight(),
                    ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
            mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Image is available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
            }, null);

            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface, recordSurface, mImageReader.getSurface()),
                    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            cameraCaptureSessions = session;
                            try {
                                cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(
                                        captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, null
                                );
                            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to configure session", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, null);
            mediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener(new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onError(MediaRecorder mediaRecorder, int i, int i1) {
                    recording = false;
                }
            });
            recording = true;
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Edit:

Logcat of the device.

```
07-15 23:29:43.339  1243  1597 E StagefrightRecorder: Failed to create video encoder
07-15 23:29:43.339  1243  1597 D MPEG4Writer: reset()
07-15 23:29:43.339  1243  1597 D MPEG4Writer: release()
07-15 23:29:43.340  5615  5615 E MediaRecorder: prepare failed: -2147483648
07-15 23:29:43.340  5615  5615 W System.err: java.io.IOException: prepare failed.
07-15 23:29:43.342  5615  5615 W System.err:    at android.media.MediaRecorder._prepare(Native Method)
07-15 23:29:43.342  5615  5615 W System.err:    at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:1436)
07-15 23:29:43.342  5615  5615 W System.err:    at xyz.kumaraswamy.procam.CameraBase.recordVideo(CameraService.java:199)
07-15 23:29:43.342  5615  5615 W System.err:    at xyz.kumaraswamy.procam.CameraService.startRecording(CameraService.java:108)
07-15 23:29:43.342  5615  5615 W System.err:    at xyz.kumaraswamy.procam.CameraService.access$200(CameraService.java:41)
07-15 23:29:43.342  5615  5615 W System.err:    at xyz.kumaraswamy.procam.CameraService$MessageHandler.handleMessage(CameraService.java:58)
07-15 23:29:43.342  5615  5615 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
07-15 23:29:43.342  5615  5615 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
07-15 23:29:43.342  5615  5615 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
07-15 23:29:43.342  5615  5615 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-15 23:29:43.342  5615  5615 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
07-15 23:29:43.342  5615  5615 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
07-15 23:29:43.404   917  6365 E mm-camera: <IFACE ><ERROR> 2441: iface_axi_handle_sof_event: Event SOF session 3 VFE1, src 0 with frame_id 30 ts: 5419428895000
```

It is the problem with the video encoder, I set it to default, but the error still exists.

Comment: You might want to see what the full-device logcat says at the time of the error; there may be more details there on what exactly failed.  Does this work if you use an appropriate CamcorderProfile instead of setting values yourself?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you.